# Give Chrome extension access to iframe contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I've made a Chrome Extension that loads my New Tab page with an `<iframe>` of my YouTube subscription page (I got around the `X-frame-options` issue) and want to isolate a specific element of the document, `#content` to be exact (that being the subscription feed). Whether that be subtracting everything that is `:not(#content)` or cutting `#content` out and putting it into another `<div>` are both viable. Here's my code:

**Background.html**

```
<html> 
    <head>   
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="window.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe id="left"  name="left"></iframe>
        <div id="canvas"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Window.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $left = $('#left');    
    $left.on('load', function() {
        $(this).contents().find('#content').clone().appendTo('#canvas');
    });    
    $left.attr('src', 'https://www.youtube.com/feed/subscriptions');    
});
```

**Script.js**

```
chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(
    function(info) {
        var headers = info.responseHeaders;
        for (var i = headers.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
            var header = headers[i].name.toLowerCase();
            if (header == 'x-frame-options' || header == 'frame-options') {
                headers.splice(i, 1); // Remove header
            }
        }
        return {
            responseHeaders: headers
        };
    }, {
        urls: ['*://*/*'], // Pattern to match all http(s) pages
        types: ['sub_frame']
    }, ['blocking', 'responseHeaders']
);
```

**Manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "version": "1.0",

    "background": "background.html",

    "chrome_url_overrides" : {
        "newtab": "background.html"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "background",
        "contextMenus",
        "webRequest",
        "webRequestBlocking",
        "tabs",
        "<all_urls>"
    ]   
}
```

As it is right now, YouTube loads, but I can't get a hold of the document in the `<iframe>`, as it's logging an error of:

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 
'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "chrome-extension://ID" from 
accessing a frame with origin "https://www.youtube.com".  The frame requesting 
access has a protocol of "chrome-extension", the frame being accessed has a 
protocol of "https". Protocols must match.
```

I'm trying to get that `div#content`isolated for ease of navigation from my new tab page. I've seen solutions that propose using `"all_frames":true` in the `manifest.json` file, but that doesn't seem to solve it. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/8917593/32453

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the description here and chrome extension related questions you asked these days, I'd like to suggest you learn more from [Official Guide](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions), since it seems you are confused by [Event page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages) and [content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) ( you should know all_frames only apply to content scripts).

Take a look at [Same-origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) and you should know Chrome extension doesn't allow you to access contentDocument of the iframe.

Since your purpose is to extract the #content part from youtube then append that to your canvas in new tab page, why not

1. just send a ajax request to youtube
2. parse the returned html response and extract the #content part
3. then append it to canvas

The code looks like:

Manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "Your extension name",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "version": "1.0",
    "chrome_url_overrides": {
        "newtab": "newtab.html"
    }, 
    "permissions": [
        "https://www.youtube.com/feed/subscriptions/*"
    ]
}
```

newtab.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
    <head>   
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="canvas"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
$.post("https://www.youtube.com/feed/subscriptions", function(html) {
   $(html).find("#content").appendTo('#canvas');
});
```

Please be aware that the original image src in youtube page looks like `src="//..."`, you should add the right domain before `//` in your chrome extension. And youtube has many scripts to load, you also need to deal with that part of logic.

**Last by not least**, I think the best way is to find some public 3rd party api from youtube, I didn't use it but it seems [Youtube | Google Developer](https://developers.google.com/youtube/) may help.

Comment: Thanks! I'm looking into it.

Comment: How exactly would I load the many scripts that YouTube has? Right now I'm trying to load the page and then cut out everything but `#content` and elements with the `script` or `link` tags. Yet it still loads with no styling. How would I solve this? Also, even when I try to load the request and NOT cut out anything, it loads with no styling applied and no `body` or `html` tags.

Comment: Considering the workload, I suggest you learn more about [Youtube | Google Developer](https://developers.google.com/youtube/), and for subscriptions, it seems [Implementation and Migration: Subscriptions](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/implementation/subscriptions) should help.